# Analyze the time and space complexity of the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

Problem from leetcode:

> https://leetcode.com/problems/text-justification/description/
>
> Given an array of words and a width maxWidth, format the text such that each line has exactly maxWidth characters and is fully (left and right) justified.
>
> You should pack your words in a greedy approach; that is, pack as many words as you can in each line. Pad extra spaces ' ' when necessary so that each line has exactly maxWidth characters.
>
> Extra spaces between words should be distributed as evenly as possible. If the number of spaces on a line do not divide evenly between words, the empty slots on the left will be assigned more spaces than the slots on the right.
>
> For the last line of text, it should be left justified and no extra space is inserted between words.

Original code:

```
   class Solution:
        def fullJustify(self, words, maxWidth):
            ans, curr, word_length = [], [], 0
            words.append(' ' * maxWidth)
            for w in words:
                if word_length + len(w) + len(curr) > maxWidth:
                    space = maxWidth-word_length 
                    if w != words[-1]:
                        for i in range(space):
                            curr[i%(len(curr)-1 or 1)] += ' '
                        ans.append(''.join(curr))
                    else:
                        ans.append(' '.join(curr) + ' ' * (space - (len(curr) - 1)))
                    curr = []
                    word_length = 0
                curr += [w]
                word_length += len(w)            

            return ans
```

So there are 2 for-loops, one is inside another.
The second for-loop is determined by the space which change everytime but always smaller than 'maxWidth'. First loop has time-complexity of O(n), what's the overall time complexity?

Comment: O(m*n) is the time complexity

Answer (score 0):

If you call n = |words| and m = maxWidth then you'll notice that you have an outer loop that does n iterations, inside of that there are different conditions but if they happen to be true you have another loop that in the worst case scenario is executed m times.

Therefore you can say time complexity is: **T(n, m) = O(n * m)**